# Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS is now released, and posts about it are (generally) No Longer Offtopic

Tags: discussion, scope

As of about 23:00 UTC on April 26, 2018, **Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS** has been officially released.  The corresponding release announcement email that went out to the `ubuntu-announce` mailing list is [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-April/000231.html).

Therefore, effective as of this post, new 18.04 questions are now to be considered **on topic** here so long as they comply with the other requirements for on topic posts as defined in the [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and here on Meta.

This does not mean that 'older' 18.04 questions can be reopened without discussion or community consensus.  Questions which were closed because 18.04 at the time was off topic or questions which are related to upgrading or using 18.04 *prior* to its official release remain offtopic, unless the community at-large believes (on a case-by-case basis) specific posts should be reopened.

***CLOSE REVIEWERS***: Do not close new 18.04 questions as "offtopic", effective as of the time of this post, unless they are offtopic for some reason *other* than the question being about 18.04

Comment: Related comments about closing 18.04 on April 26 under this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028275/when-will-ubuntu-18-04-release-and-at-what-time#comment1672002_1028275 The comment conversation took place before the software was  released later that day. The software was probably released about the time Thomas's question here was posted. *whistles whilst ignoring the fact this is an answer in the question section* :p

Comment: Ridiculous rule, especially since a pre-release version can be made into the release version by means of `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` on the day of release. It'd be way more sensible to use one of the beta versions as the cut-off. Because even though there might be issues that aren't part of the final release, leading to questions, the overall amount of changes that went into it are a much more likely reason for questions than *prerelease-specific* issues.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Comments on that rule are in *other* threads, not this one.  If you have an issue with policy, open a new thread and be *civil* with your arguments in an attempt to change policy. This post here was made solely to indicate the "new" Ubuntu release was now officially on topic as of its release date/time.