# Can users raise questions on the day of the announced release date irrespective of time?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Can users raise questions on the day of the announced release date irrespective of time or will they be closed?

To be specific, Ubuntu 20.04 will be released on the 23rd Of April.
But some countries will have a different date due to timezone difference.

Will these questions still be closed, I mean do we need to wait until the next day of its release day?

Example reasons for closing the questions:

[Ubuntu 20.04 extension configuration error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219156/ubuntu-20-04-extension-configuration-error)

[Ubuntu Studio 20.04 FireWire compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225047/ubuntu-studio-20-04-firewire-compatibility)

Comment: @Dan.. "Examples of closed questions" is confusing.. see the comments.. let it be "Example reasons for closing the questions" ..

Answer (score 8):

The questions specific to future releases of Ubuntu are considered as off-topic until it is officially released. The release is notified by the [mailing lists](https://lists.ubuntu.com/). It's fair to consider the questions as off-topic until the ISO image on [Ubuntu Releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) is updated with the final release.

The example questions that you've mentioned were closed on 22 March 2020 and 8 April 2020 respectively. In general, the issues occured in beta stage which may or may not occur in final release. So, it isn't feasible to open the already closed questions. But if the issue still there in final release, a new question can be posted and it won't be closed as such.

**Questions/Discussions you might find interesting:**

- [At what time will the upcoming Ubuntu release be made available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65476/816190)
- [Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS is now released, and posts about it are (generally) No Longer Offtopic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17863/816190)

Comment: hi kulfy@ thats nice.. i think i have to be clear on examples i have shown in my Q. don't consider the dates.. the closure reason can still be made on its day of release is my main point which you clarified in your answer. thanks..

Comment: @PRATAP It's to be noted that 18.04 was released at 23:00 UTC and the questions specific to that remained off-topic till then. Similarly, the questions can't be considered as on-topic on 23 Apr, 00:00 UTC unless there's official announcement/release.

Comment: @Kulfy I would say the main difference is if the problems occurs on the *released* version or not. If someone asks before release, and then verify with a new install after release, that would be an valid reopen-reason to me.

Comment: @vidarlo I would like to quote [the announcement by Thomas](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19044/816190): ***This does not mean that 'older' 20.04 questions can be reopened without discussion or community consensus. Questions which were closed because 20.04 at the time was off topic or questions which are related to upgrading or using 20.04 prior to its official release remain offtopic, unless the community at-large believes (on a case-by-case basis) specific posts should be reopened.*** I'd say feel free to cast a reopen vote and comment the reason  :)

Comment: @Kulfy I do not disagree with that announcement in any way :)

Comment: @vidarlo I juts wanted to highlight "***unless the community at-large believes (on a case-by-case basis) specific posts should be reopened.***". I would say if someone thinks that a question needs to be reopened, cast a reopen vote and post a comment or post on meta with the arguments.