# Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04) LTS is now released, and posts about it are (generally) No Longer Offtopic

Tags: discussion, scope

(Meant to post this yesterday but crashed hard from lack of sleep)

As of about 17:47:04 UTC on April 23, 2020, **Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04 LTS** has been officially released.  The corresponding release announcement email that went out to the `ubuntu-announce` mailing list is [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2020-April/004969.html).

Therefore, effective as of this post, new 20.04 questions are now to be considered **on topic** here so long as they comply with the other requirements for on topic posts as defined in the [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and here on Meta.

This does not mean that 'older' 20.04 questions can be reopened without discussion or community consensus.  Questions which were closed because 20.04 at the time was off topic or questions which are related to upgrading or using 20.04 *prior* to its official release remain offtopic, unless the community at-large believes (on a case-by-case basis) specific posts should be reopened.

***CLOSE REVIEWERS***: Do not close new 20.04 questions as "offtopic", effective as of the time of this post, unless they are offtopic for some reason *other* than the question being about 20.04

Comment: Note that the recommended upgrade process currently [displays](https://askubuntu.com/q/1230419/1859) the announcement of the *development* release, which is causing some [confusion](https://askubuntu.com/q/1229890/1859) about whether 20.04 LTS is actually on-topic yet.

Comment: @ændrük Which is why this post exists to indicate ontopicness. HOWEVER the upgrade path takes a few days to turn on - that will be done by the release team then it wont show as the Development release in the upgrade.

Comment: I suggest making the upgrade questions off-topic until the path is opened. The reason is the same as the beta questions. There are problems, many of them will be fixed soon. Upgrading problems before creates lots of questions that will become obsolete in a week or two.

Comment: @ThomasWard "Which is why this post exists…"—My apologies if I've put you on the defensive. My intention is to add information to the announcement, not rebut it.

Comment: Beware of the development release, my system had trouble to start after upgrade today. Cursor could move but system did not react to any action. Please also create an appropriate tag for Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: @iArnold regarding the tag, there's already a 20.04 tag.  `20.4` (incorrect) is NOT `20.04` (which is correct)

Answer (score 5):

I gotta put here 2 cases that could be posted here but are actually bugs that I experienced:

**Nvidia + Auto Login** - If you have an Nvidia card and install the driver (during the initial ISO setup) or upgrade from 19.10 or 18.04, and during this time, you either had Auto-Login enabled or set it up during the ISO setup), then you will encounter an issue where the Login screen won't let you log to the desktop. You will end up in a infinite loop. The issues is mentioned in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1845801

The workaround is adding `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to the default `/etc/default/grub` file so that the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** option looks like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"`

Then rebooting. But this is actually a bug that is being worked on.

**CUT/COPY in LibreOffice and other apps fails randomly** - The bug was first mentioned in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183 but basically, if you try to copy or cut quickly from one cell to another one in LibreOffice Calc (or other similar apps), it will fail and not paste correctly (or do other weird thing). The issues has been related to the Clipboard Extension, the GSConnect app and others. The bug is fixed in Mutter 3.36.2 (Currently Ubuntu 20.04 has 3.36.1) and will come to Ubuntu once it pushes this changes.

Of course there are other bug reports that can be found at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+bugs

But this are the big ones I have encountered with other developers having the exact same issues.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I hope Mutter 3.36.2 will be pushed to Ubuntu 20.04 very soon, the copy+cut/paste-issue is really disrupting. Is there a way to lobby for that?

Comment: @Filbuntu Go to the bug report and vote that it is also happening to you. Then lift your first in an angry manner to the sky and yell at the world.

Comment: I hoped there is more I can do, e.g. email a decision maker or start a petition on Ubuntu discourse or something else more active. I have voted for the bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183) a long time ago and was delighted to hear about the fix: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1113. And I have already lifted my fist many times virtually but it did not yet help :(. Maybe I pray for a fix although I have not yet prayed for a bug fix but why not ;) .

Comment: So far there are no tags for "focal" or "fossa".  Could someone with more than 300 reputation points add them, please?

Comment: The CUT/COPY issue is also the subject of *[Copy and paste issue with Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188960)*. It may never be fixed.

Comment: Hi @PeterMortensen I have faith in Gnome that one day https://download.gnome.org/core/3.36/3.36.2/NEWS cough cough, they will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to comment on the initial post, but I don't have the required reputation yet, so here I go.

It is stated above:

> CLOSE REVIEWERS: Do not close new 20.04 questions as "offtopic", effective as of the time of this post

however I posted my *Fossa* related question on the following URL, and it was *closed*:
[Problem with open-mpi in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227945/problem-with-open-mpi-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Could you also please have a look? I filed in *Launchpad* under the following

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1873793

Thanks,

Comment: I am not commenting on your specific question, but I would like to point out that bug reports are always off-topic (regardless of whether the Ubuntu release in question is supported or not). The closure message says "Bug reports **and** problems specific to development version of Ubuntu...".